# SUM the same field on different CASE conditions

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by

I have a table with the following fields.

```
code    quantity    active

1       23          true
1       35          true
1       25          false
1       37          false
2       30          true
2       43          true
2       43          false
2       45          true
3       49          false
3       26          false
3       30          true
3       46          false
3       46          false
3       27          true
4       42          false
4       23          false
4       48          true
4       35          false
4       45          true
```

and I have the following query:

```
SELECT code, CASE WHEN active THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS "activeCodes", 
CASE WHEN active=false THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS "inactiveCodes" 
FROM tbl_codes 
GROUP BY code, active
ORDER BY code
```

and the result of it is the following table:

```
code    activeCodes    inactiveCodes

1       0              2
1       2              0
2       3              0
2       0              1
3       0              4
3       2              0
4       0              3
4       2              0
```

but the result that I expected is

```
code     activeCodes        inactiveCodes

1        2                  2
2        3                  1
3        4                  2
4        2                  3
```

which condition am I missing here? how can I get the result that I expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sparse matrix which you can collapse by running a `SUM`. Probably something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT code
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN active THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "activeCodes"
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN active=false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "inactiveCodes" 
  FROM tbl_codes 
  GROUP BY code
  ORDER BY code
```